# How to keep value during recursive calls in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to keep the value of a variable static during recursive calls, for example if `foo` is a function that takes `name` as a parameter, i want to save the value of `name`  from the first call to `foo` in a variable and the variable will retain the value in every recursive call to foo.

```
def run_app (name, startr)
  if startr==1
    constant_var=name
  end

  some_name = modify name
  diff = compare some_name, constant_var

  # recursive call
  run_app some_name, 0
end
```

First call will be like, `run_app "john", 1` I want the value of constant_var to be retained during the calls. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, there's some redundancy in your code. `diff` is assigned but never used. You can just get rid of it:

```
def run_app(name, startr)
  constant_var = name if startr == 1

  some_name = modify name
  compare(some_name, constant_var)

  # recursive call
  run_app(some_name, 0)
end
```

The standard way of solving this would be to add an extra parameter for passing along that extra information:

```
def run_app(name, startr, constant_var)
  some_name = modify name
  compare(some_name, constant_var)

  # recursive call
  run_app(some_name, 0, constant_var)
end
```

Then you need to call the method like this:

```
run_app(tmp = 'john', 1, tmp)

# or

run_app('john', 2, nil)
```

However, this leaks a *ton* of internal implementation details out to the caller and places a heavy burden on them. For example, they need to know that the first and third argument need to be the same object. But only if they pass `1` as the second argument. If they pass something other than `1`, then they need to pass `nil` as the third argument.

What's to stop someone from calling

```
run_app('john', 1, 'ringo')

# or 

run_app(tmp = 'john', 2, tmp)
```

You can slightly improve that by using an optional parameter with a default argument:

```
def run_app(name, startr, constant_var = name if startr == 1)
  some_name = modify name
  compare(some_name, constant_var)

  # recursive call
  run_app(some_name, 0, constant_var)
end
```

Now you can call it like you want to:

```
run_app('john', 1)

# or

run_app('john', 2)
```

However, you can *still* call it like this:

```
run_app('john', 1, 'ringo')

# or 

run_app(tmp = 'john', 2, tmp)
```

So, what we do is to move that logic into a `private` helper method and give the public method the API we want:

```
def run_app(name, startr)
  constant_var = name if startr == 1

  run_app_r(name, startr, constant_var)
end

private

def run_app_r(name, startr, constant_var)
  some_name = modify name
  compare(some_name, constant_var)

  # recursive call
  run_app_r(some_name, 0, constant_var)
end
```

Call it like this:

```
run_app('john', 1)

# or

run_app('john', 2)
```

Of course, you can now *still* call

```
run_app_r('john', 1, 'ringo')

# or 

run_app_r(tmp = 'john', 2, tmp)
```

But at least you now have a *separate* method which you can clearly document as `private`, e.g. by using YARD's `@private` tag or just use RDoc's `:nodoc:` tag to leave it out of the docs completely.

The fact that the `run_app_r` method can be called from everywhere even though it is only meant to be called inside `run_app` is pretty annoying. In a language like Scala which supports nested methods you would just put the `run_app_r` method inside of the `run_app` method, but Ruby doesn't support nested methods, so we have to find another way: `Proc`s can be nested inside methods!

```
def run_app(name, startr)
  constant_var = name if startr == 1

  (run_app_r = ->(name, startr, constant_var; some_name) {
    some_name = modify name
    compare(some_name, constant_var)

    # recursive call
    run_app_r.(some_name, 0, constant_var)
  }).(name, startr, constant_var)
end
```

Call it like this:

```
run_app('john', 1)

# or

run_app('john', 2)
```

And since blocks are closures, we don't even need to explicitly pass `constant_var` along:

```
def run_app(name, startr)
  constant_var = name if startr == 1

  (run_app_r = ->(name, startr; some_name) {
    some_name = modify name
    compare(some_name, constant_var)

    # recursive call
    run_app_r.(some_name, 0)
  }).(name, startr)
end
```

Call it like this:

```
run_app('john', 1)

# or

run_app('john', 2)
```

But all of this is moot, because your recursion doesn't have a base case and thus will loop infinitely. Or rather, you will get a stack overflow because Ruby doesn't guarantee proper tail calls.

Comment: Hi thanks for the elaborated answer, i put a facade code mostly. the actual code is much different with loop terminator. The facade code was given to mainly focus on the main issue i tried to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a parameter for the modified name:

```
def run_app (name, modified_name=name)
  # do something with name
  modified_name = modify(name)

  # recursive call
  run_app name, modified_name
end
```

You can then call the method with just `run_app("John")`

Comment: Actually i modified the name and pass it in the recursive function call, so passing it would not suffice. i can have an extra parameter to do the job, but looking forward to knowing other ways if available.

Comment: Then i would go with an extra variable for the modified name, see my edit

Comment: Btw i think requiring the user of the method to pass the correct value `0` as a parameter to the first call is bad design. I strongly recommend the use of default parameters.

Comment: I changed my code, i think now you will get my intention accurately.

Comment: yeah i thought there will be other solutions than the extra parameter. looks like it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write a wrapper to your recursive call which stores the variable somewhere before calling the actual function. Perhaps as a member variable of your class.

```
def run_wrapper(name, startr)
    @orig_name = name

    run_app (name, startr)
end

def run_app(name, startr)
    p @orig_name
end
```

A more cleaner way might be to add a third param

```
def run_app(name, startr, orig_name = nil)
    ...
    run_app("blah", startr-1, orig_name || name)
end
```

Comment: actually the initial value that was saved in the constant_var will be used each time to compare with the name parameters in each recursive call. so it needs to work within the recursive function.

Comment: please see my modified code. I need to use the name inside the recursive function.

Comment: @Pbasak I am printing the constant within the recursive function.. isnt this enough?

Comment: ok will the orig_name is visible (within the scope) inside run_app (as it is a different function)?  i did not think so. Will test it.

Comment: @Pbasak look up class member variables, when you say `@` something, that creates a variable that is attached to your `self` object, this means that these should be member functions of a class and not free functions btw.

Comment: yeah i thought there will be other solutions than the extra parameter. looks like it is the best way.